# How to resolve server tag not well formed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to refresh content of a div which has captcha image without reloading entire page. I have a hyperlink link button which reloads the html of the div when clicked.

```
 function refreshcaptcha() {

            $('#tbl_captcha').html("<div id='tbl_captcha' style='text-align:center'><table  style='text-align:center; width:250px' ><tr ><cc1:CaptchaControl ID='Captcha1' runat='server' Font-Bold='true' CaptchaBackgroundNoise='Low' CaptchaLength='5'CaptchaHeight='60' CaptchaWidth='300'CaptchaLineNoise='None' CaptchaMinTimeout='5'CaptchaMaxTimeout='240' FontColor = '#529E00' /></tr></table></div>");

        }
```

now I am getting server tag is not well formed. I understand the error that my runat=server is not in double quotes but couldn't find a solution. Can someone please help?

Comment: `runat="server"` is irrelevant in the client side context, though it won't cause any issues, however, `cc1:CaptchaControl` likely will

Comment: As @andrew addressed, it looks like you're attempting to add a server control through a client script block, which doesn't work. Keep in mind, server controls are processed and rendered through the page lifecycle when the response is sent to the user. I think you need to come at this problem differently.